# The Tail Sum for $e$ and $n$

Tags: calculus

I want a *hint* on how to solve this problem:
Find the limit of the sum:
$$\dfrac1{7n+1} + \dfrac{2^{1/2}}{7n+2} + \dfrac{3^{1/3}}{7n+3} + \cdots + \dfrac{(70n)^{1/70n}}{77n}$$ when $n \to \infty$. I try to use Stolz Cesaro theorem and the definition of Riemann sum but believe I miss a big trick !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not completely sure if the argument below is right but anyway here she is.
\begin{align}
f(n) & = \sum_{k=1}^{70n} \dfrac{k^{1/k}}{7n+k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}} \dfrac{k^{1/k}}{7n+k} + \sum_{k=\sqrt{n}}^{70n} \dfrac{k^{1/k}}{7n+k}
\end{align}
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{n}} \dfrac{k^{1/k}}{7n+k} = \mathcal{O}(1/\sqrt{n})$$
For large enough $n$, we have $k^{1/k} \sim 1 + \mathcal{O}(\log(n)/\sqrt{n})$ for $k \in (\sqrt{n}, 70n)$. Hence,
$$\sum_{k=\sqrt{n}}^{70n} \dfrac{k^{1/k}}{7n+k} \sim \sum_{k=\sqrt{n}}^{70n} \dfrac{1}{7n+k} = \int_0^{70} \dfrac{dx}{7+x} = \ln(11)$$
Hence, the limit is $\ln(11)$.

Comment: @MatikKen I would then assume the limit would be $L$ times the above.

Comment: That was a _hint_? What would a full answer look like?

Comment: @IgorRivin If I leave a hint, I get down-voted for answering fast without providing the details. If I give some details, then I get down-voted for answering in detail and not giving a hint.

Comment: @user17762 But in this case the OP explicitly asked for a hint (and no, I did not downvote you, but given the phrasing of the question I did not feel it right to upvote what was otherwise a very nice answer).

Comment: @Pleasedeleteaccount I don't think it's worth to delete your very nice answers, I still need to go through them and learn things there :-). For instance, at a certain point I wanted to do the same thing, to delete my account, but then I changed my mind because there are also many people that appreciated things I did. I'm not active anymore on main, but I like to join the chat. You might do the same. It's an idea. :-)

Comment: I think the answer is $\log(11)$.

Comment: @Chris'ssis True. Thanks. Few good people still around M.SE.

Comment: For your second line, you can say $k^{1/k}\lt e^{1/e}$, which is $O(1)$  You can then delete the line "For large enough $n$", which is nice because the left side depends on $k$ while the right depends on $n$.  In the conversion of sum to integral, you need to justify the lower limit doesn't change things.